# MPF Project : VS Package Build Event Not calling in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vspackage, vs-extensibility, mpf

I am working with custom project creation for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 and creating our own VS package with project type *.myproj

It is working fine with VS 2013. But in VS 2012 my code for the below method is only calling for the first time, once I have closed the application and reopened the below method is not called.

```
public void BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin(EnvDTE.vsBuildScope Scope, EnvDTE.vsBuildAction Action)
        {}
```

Any suggestions are welcomed. I struggle at this place since this is my first attempt on creating custom project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that your event handler is being garbage-collected. Ensure that your code doesn't have this issue:

PRB: Visual Studio .NET events being disconnected from add-in.
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005012.aspx